# Should commonly posted duplicate homework questions be flagged (or filtered) as spam?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, flagging

I speak in particular reference to this question from today:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/318075/135943

Which is an exact duplicate (in different words) of the same homework question from a different user posted *yesterday*:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/317816/135943

The same question was asked twice in October 2014, one of them with a slight twist (copying instead of removing, but the same example directory tree):

- [Remove parent and sub directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164762/135943)
- [How can I copy a file from another directory to the current one?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/162354/135943)

The "copying" form was also posted in June 2015:

- [Copying and relative Home](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/211656/135943)

There is [a comment on this last post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211656/copying-and-relative-home#comment358558_211656) that sums up the situation (links are at the original but here is the text):

> In addition to the 2014 duplicate here on Unix & Linux already pointed out, this was asked on Yahoo Answers Canada and on StackOverflow (stackoverflow.com/questions/19193933) in 2013. It's part of the coursework for ULI101 at Seneca College. This year's is due in 3 days' time, and the course page says that all assignments "MUST consist of the student’s OWN work". I suspect that getting a bunch of people here to do it doesn't count. – JdeBP Jun 23 '15 at 20:43

---

These are annoying and not the purpose of the site.  It is a relatively minor occurrence, but it spans <s>three</s> **four** different years now, if you count the Stack Overflow question as well.

- Should any new posts of this type be flagged as spam?
- Should any filters be modified to reject these questions?

Comment: Vote to Close as Off-Topic. Use the custom field and let them know that the entire point of homework is that the student is the one making an effort, not this community.

Comment: See also https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/108136/65097 .